# How to change tty's text size/scale on 4k resolution screen OR force lower screen resolution?

Tags: display-resolution, tty

All DEFAULT Ubuntu Server 20.04.1 LTS installation (without Xorg) + 4k hdmi display = not readable tiny text in the console.

Setting GRUB_GFXMODE in /etc/default/grub ([from this answer and similar threads](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041677/how-to-change-the-login-screen-resolution-in-ubuntu-18-04)) affects only GRUB black and white console output (on bootup), then it jumps to color loading and login Ubuntu console [image: "color loading and login Ubuntu console"].

On the monitor with 1080p maximum resolution text scale is normal.

Comment: Please clarify what you mean with "color loading and login Ubuntu console". Is a graphical environment loaded or not?

Comment: @NateT xrandr is only applicable if Xorg is running. Typically not on a server.

Comment: Is the log not recorded? Why not just look at it from inside the OS after boot if it will not resize in the TTY?

Answer (score 0):

From Google:

> To adjust the font/font-size used for the TTY, run sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup , which will guide you through the steps to choose a font and font-size...

This is what I get when googling. But I cannot vouch personally for this, as I have never tried it personally. My advice would be to look into the `console-setup` package.`dpkg-reconfigure` has a man-page, and is a fairly common command. It is part of the `debconf` package, and is the same as running `sudo dpkg --reconfigure`.

I will [link the result](https://www.google.com/search?q=adjust+tty+font&client=ubuntu&hs=gN0&channel=fs&sxsrf=AOaemvIj6FpWRAP2e4k3fQPHuj6_EoA-9w%3A1630230083224&ei=Q1YrYfyMDYmyqtsPyaOWyAQ&oq=adjust+tty&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYADIGCAAQFhAeOgcIABBHELADOgcIABCwAxBDOgQIIxAnOgUIABCABDoKCAAQgAQQhwIQFDoHCCMQ6gIQJzoECAAQQzoRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QM6DgguEIAEELEDEMcBENEDOgsILhCABBCxAxCDAToOCC4QgAQQsQMQxwEQowI6BQgAEJECOggIABCABBCxAzoFCAAQsQM6CAgAEBYQChAeSgQIQRgAUITE0QFY-4_SAWDfuNIBaAJwAngDgAGaAYgBhxCSAQQwLjE3mAEAoAEBsAEKyAEKwAEB&sclient=gws-wiz), to give you a lead into your research. From what I  can tell, you will get a prompt menu that walks you through the process, making it fairly straightforward, but I would recommend confirming for yourself. This is meant only to point you in the general direction of the answer.

Comment: This answer is not applicable: the question is about the font size in the tty, i.e. the terminal before any graphical server is loaded, or which you can reach with Ctrl+Alt+F3 and up. You may consider deleting the answer.

Comment: @vanadium hail mary. Does this look better? Mind you, it is google's answer, not mine, but I'm hoping it is at least vaguely helpful this time..