# xRDP login dialog really small

Tags: 22.04, login-screen, xrdp, hyper-v

My laptop that I'm using has a 3840x2160 13" screen. I'm using a Ubuntu 22.04 image on Hyper-V that I got from Microsoft. When I connect to it everything works fine except for one thing the login page for xRDP is really small. Once logged in I had a similar issue but was able to set the display scale to 300% which looks normal on my screen. Is there a way to scale the login screen up in the same way?

Comment: You might have luck copying your `monitors.xml` file to the GDM3 config folder so that it matches your desktop.  See: https://askubuntu.com/a/1046942/231142  I know the answer was back in 2018, but it still works today.  All you should have to do is copy the file and not edit it like the answer says.

Comment: I tried this and it does not seem to have worked.

Comment: Make sure that the `monitors.xml` file is in the `/var/lib/gdm3/.config/` folder.  You might need to run `sudo ls -al /var/lib/gdm3/.config/` to see if the file is there.

Answer (score 0):

This is a know situation with xRDP and DPI... Indeed, you will get a really small xRDP screen when working with high resolution screen.

The latest version (Stable) of the package does not fix yet this issue.  However, it seems that the team behind the xRDP software is aware of the issue and they have updated the code in the Dev Branch

To "fix" your issue today,  you should compile xRDP (Dev Branch) from source and this should include the code that would fix the xRDP login resolution....

You can find information on how to compile from source at https://github.com/neutrinolabs/xrdp/wiki

Hope this help
Till next time